# Android studio NumberFormatException causes crash

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio

whenever I try to run my Activity,
I always have a crash at the line

`total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));`

Actually all the loadListFood method crashes !

My Activity

```
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {
   RecyclerView recyclerView;
   RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
   //
   FirebaseDatabase database;
   DatabaseReference requests;
   //
   TextView txtTotalPrice;
   Button btnPlace;

List<Order>  cart = new ArrayList<>();


CartAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        //// Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        requests = database.getReference("Requests");
        // INIT
        recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.listCart);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager  = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        //
        txtTotalPrice =findViewById(R.id.total);
        btnPlace =findViewById(R.id.btnPlaceOrder);
      btnPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           /// Create new Request
           showAlertDialoge();
        }
    });
        loadListFood();
    }



    private void loadListFood() {
        cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
        adapter = new CartAdapter(cart,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //calculation

        int total =0;
        for(Order order :cart)
            total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));
        Locale locale= new Locale("en","US");
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));

        }



    }
```

logcat:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.OverRout.app/com.OverRout.app.Cart}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Hunger "
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Okay"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
        at com.OverRout.app.Cart.loadListFood(Cart.java:128)
        at com.OverRout.app.Cart.onCreate(Cart.java:66)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Okay"   says: "You are sending a String value called Okay" however the input is waiting that you enter a integer value for example "7".

Comment: you should post order.getPrice() or order.getQuantity here as well

Answer (score 0):

This line here says what is the problem:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Okay"

You're trying to transform the string "Okay" to a number and this will never work, you need a number of some sort, like "65".

If this is a input you should consider setting the input as number and then the keyboard will not have any letters.